# Is there a Tcl_GetInt version for unsigned __int64

Tags: tcl

Looking at [Tcl_GetInt](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/GetInt.htm), I need this type of function for an `unsigned __int64` which is unfortunately not present in `tclDecls.h`

**tclDecls.h** can be found in

```
Tcl8.6.5\include
```

Is it safe to use `Tcl_GetDouble` and convert it later to `unsigned __int64`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Tcl_GetWideIntFromObj`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclLib/IntObj.htm) to obtain a `Tcl_WideInt`, or better a `Tcl_WideUInt`. Then cast to `unsigned __int64`, if need be.

> Is it safe to use Tcl_GetDouble and convert it later to unsigned __int64?

It depends: [Safe conversion from double to unsigned 64 bit integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332440/safe-conversion-from-double-to-unsigned-64-bit-integer)