# Double cast to unsigned int on Win32 is truncating to 2,147,483,648

Tags: c, visual-c++, casting, x86, floating-point

Compiling the following code:

```c
double getDouble()
{
    double value = 2147483649.0;
    return value;
}

int main()
{
     printf("INT_MAX: %u\n", INT_MAX);
     printf("UINT_MAX: %u\n", UINT_MAX);

     printf("Double value: %f\n", getDouble());
     printf("Direct cast value: %u\n", (unsigned int) getDouble());
     double d = getDouble();
     printf("Indirect cast value: %u\n", (unsigned int) d);

     return 0;
}
```

Outputs (MSVC x86):

```
INT_MAX: 2147483647
UINT_MAX: 4294967295
Double value: 2147483649.000000
Direct cast value: 2147483648
Indirect cast value: 2147483649
```

Outputs (MSVC x64):

```
INT_MAX: 2147483647
UINT_MAX: 4294967295
Double value: 2147483649.000000
Direct cast value: 2147483649
Indirect cast value: 2147483649
```

In [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/conversions-from-floating-point-types?view=vs-2019) there is no mention to signed integer max value in conversions from `double` to `unsigned int`.

All values above `INT_MAX` are being truncated to `2147483648` when it is the return of a function.

I'm using *Visual Studio 2019* to build the program. This doesn't happen on *gcc*.

Am I doing someting wrong? Is there a safe way to convert `double` to `unsigned int`?

Comment: Are you certain this applies to *all* values? Could you provide the disassembly too from MSVC?

Comment: And no, you're not doing anything wrong (perhaps besides trying to use Microsoft's "C" compiler)

Comment: Could you please add the includes too, so that we can verify that it indeed is the same code, and not the case of inverting the function definition order, or something similar?

Comment: Cannot replicate this with 32-bit MSVC compiler . All values output are `2147483649` here.

Comment: Works on my machine™, tested on VS2017 v15.9.18 and VS2019 v16.4.1.  Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Bug to tell them about your version.

Comment: I'm able reproduce, I have the same results as those of the OP. VS2019 16.7.3.

Comment: @anastaciu so could you produce the assembly to the question :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala https://codeshare.io/aYQ8wN

Comment: [This might be related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3332678/918959):  - see [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3332483/918959) :/

Comment: @anastaciu C++ ;)

Comment: `__ftol2_sse` seems to be the key here, the function name is so wrong :/

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, :) yes, changed it.

Comment: Regarding the title, 2,147,483,648 is not `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil indeed, it is the bit-pattern of `INT_MIN`

Comment: Or rather, `LONG_MIN` :P

Comment: [Fix pending](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1191192/casting-double-to-unsigned-int-is-truncating-to-21.html)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, well done, they won't like your comment though ;)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

A compiler bug...

From assembly provided by @anastaciu, the direct cast code calls `__ftol2_sse`, which seems to convert the number to a *signed long*. The routine name is `ftol2_sse` because this is an sse-enabled machine - but the float is in a x87 floating point register.

```
; Line 17
    call    _getDouble
    call    __ftol2_sse
    push    eax
    push    OFFSET ??_C@_0BH@GDLBDFEH@Direct?5cast?5value?3?5?$CFu?6@
    call    _printf
    add esp, 8
```

The indirect cast on the other hand does

```
; Line 18
    call    _getDouble
    fstp    QWORD PTR _d$[ebp]
; Line 19
    movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR _d$[ebp]
    call    __dtoui3
    push    eax
    push    OFFSET ??_C@_0BJ@HCKMOBHF@Indirect?5cast?5value?3?5?$CFu?6@
    call    _printf
    add esp, 8
```

which pops and stores the double value to the local variable, then loads it into a SSE register and calls `__dtoui3` which is a double to unsigned int conversion routine...

The behaviour of the direct cast does not conform to C89; nor does it conform to any later revision - **even** C89 explicitly says that:

> The remaindering operation done when a value of integral type is converted to unsigned type need not be done when a value of floating type is converted to unsigned type. Thus the range of portable values is **[0, Utype_MAX + 1)**.

---

I believe the problem might be a [continuation of this from 2005](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d9e8ad86-1677-4687-8f94-a9d308a87619/has-casting-to-int-from-double-changed-completely-in-vs2005) - there used to be a conversion function called `__ftol2` which probably would have worked for this code, i.e. it would have converted the value to a **signed number** -2147483647, which would have produced the correct result when interpreted an unsigned number.

Unfortunately `__ftol2_sse` is not a drop-in replacement for `__ftol2`, as it would - instead of just taking the least-significant value bits as-is - signal the out-of-range error by returning `LONG_MIN` / `0x80000000`, which, interpreted as unsigned long here is not at all what was expected. The behaviour of `__ftol2_sse` would be valid for `signed long`, as conversion of a double a value > `LONG_MAX` to `signed long` would have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 23):

Following [@AnttiHaapala's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63983820/6865932), I tested the code using optimization `/Ox` and found that this will remove the bug as `__ftol2_sse` is no longer used:

```c
//; 17   :     printf("Direct cast value: %u\n", (unsigned int)getDouble());

    push    -2147483647             //; 80000001H
    push    OFFSET $SG10116
    call    _printf

//; 18   :     double d = getDouble();
//; 19   :     printf("Indirect cast value: %u\n", (unsigned int)d);

    push    -2147483647             //; 80000001H
    push    OFFSET $SG10117
    call    _printf
    add esp, 28                 //; 0000001cH
```

The optimizations inlined `getdouble()` and added constant expression evaluation thus removing the need for a conversion at runtime making the bug go away.

Just out of curiosity, I made some more tests, namely changing the code to force float-to-int conversion at runtime. In this case the result is still correct, the compiler, with optimization, uses `__dtoui3` in both conversions:

```c
//; 19   :     printf("Direct cast value: %u\n", (unsigned int)getDouble(d));

    movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR _d$[esp+24]
    add esp, 12                 //; 0000000cH
    call    __dtoui3
    push    eax
    push    OFFSET $SG9261
    call    _printf

//; 20   :     double db = getDouble(d);
//; 21   :     printf("Indirect cast value: %u\n", (unsigned int)db);

    movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR _d$[esp+20]
    add esp, 8
    call    __dtoui3
    push    eax
    push    OFFSET $SG9262
    call    _printf
```

However, preventing inlining, `__declspec(noinline) double getDouble(){...}` will bring the bug back:

```c
//; 17   :     printf("Direct cast value: %u\n", (unsigned int)getDouble(d));

    movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR _d$[esp+76]
    add esp, 4
    movsd   QWORD PTR [esp], xmm0
    call    _getDouble
    call    __ftol2_sse
    push    eax
    push    OFFSET $SG9261
    call    _printf

//; 18   :     double db = getDouble(d);

    movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR _d$[esp+80]
    add esp, 8
    movsd   QWORD PTR [esp], xmm0
    call    _getDouble

//; 19   :     printf("Indirect cast value: %u\n", (unsigned int)db);

    call    __ftol2_sse
    push    eax
    push    OFFSET $SG9262
    call    _printf
```

`__ftol2_sse` is called in both conversions making the output `2147483648` in both situations,  [@zwol suspicions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63983079/double-cast-to-unsigned-int-on-win32-is-truncating-to-2-147-483-648/63989320?noredirect=1#comment113160682_63989320) were correct.

---

**Compilation details:**

- Using command line:

```
cl /permissive- /GS /analyze- /W3 /Gm- /Ox /sdl /D "WIN32" program.c
```

- In Visual Studio:

  - Disabling `RTC` in <kbd>**Project**</kbd> `->` <kbd>**Properties**</kbd> `->` <kbd>**Code Generation**</kbd> and setting **Basic Runtime Checks** to ***default***.
  - Enabling optimization in <kbd>**Project**</kbd> `->` <kbd>**Properties**</kbd> `->` <kbd>**Optimization**</kbd> and setting **Optimization** to  ***/Ox***.
  - With debugger in `x86` mode.

Comment: Funny how they're like "ok with optimizations enabled, undefined behaviour will be really undefined" => the code actually works correctly :F

Comment: The optimizations applied were inlining and then constant expression evaluation. It's not doing a float-to-int conversion at runtime anymore. I wonder if the bug comes back if you force `getDouble` out of line and/or change it to return a value that the compiler cannot prove is constant.

Comment: @zwol, you were right, forcing out-of-line and preventing constant evaluation will bring the bug back, but this time in both conversions.

Answer (score 8):

Nobody has looked at the asm for MS's `__ftol2_sse`.

From the result, we can infer that it probably converted from x87 to signed `int` / `long` (both 32-bit types on Windows), instead of safely to `uint32_t`.

**x86 FP -> integer instructions that overflow the integer result don't just wrap / truncate: they produce what Intel calls the "integer indefinite"** when the exact value is not representable in the destination: **high bit set, other bits clear.  i.e. `0x80000000`**.

(Or if the FP invalid exception isn't masked, it fires and no value is stored.  But in the default FP environment, all FP exceptions are masked.  That's why for FP calculations you can get a NaN instead of a fault.)

That includes both x87 instructions like [`fistp`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fist:fistp) (using the current rounding mode) and SSE2 instructions like [`cvttsd2si eax, xmm0`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtsd2si) (using truncation toward 0, that's what the extra `t` means).

**So it's a bug to compile `double`->`unsigned` conversion into a call to `__ftol2_sse`.**

---

Side-note / tangent:

On x86-64, FP -> uint32_t can be compiled to `cvttsd2si rax, xmm0`, converting to a 64-bit signed destination, producing the uint32_t you want in the low half (EAX) of the integer destination.

It's C and C++ UB if the result is outside the 0..2^32-1 range so it's ok that huge positive or negative values will leave the low half of RAX (EAX) zero from the integer indefinite bit-pattern.  (Unlike integer->integer conversions, modulo reduction of the value is *not* guaranteed.  [Is the behaviour of casting a negative double to unsigned int defined in the C standard? Different behaviour on ARM vs. x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541200/is-the-behaviour-of-casting-a-negative-double-to-unsigned-int-defined-in-the-c-s).  To be clear, nothing in the *question* is undefined or even implementation-defined behaviour.  I'm just pointing out that if you have FP->int64_t, you can use it to efficiently implement FP->uint32_t.  That includes x87 `fistp` which can write a 64-bit integer destination even in 32-bit and 16-bit mode, unlike SSE2 instructions which can only directly handle 64-bit integers in 64-bit mode.

Comment: I would be tempted to look into that code but fortunately I do not have MSVC... :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Yeah, neither do I

Comment: You can download it for free now (Community Edition), for research purposes of course

Comment: `_dtoui3` also raises a FP invalid exception when converting values that exceed the uint value range. (I noticed this, since VS2017 called `_ftol3` for a conversion from FP intermediate results stored in XMM registers to unsigned long int (without exception), while VS2019 now calls `_dtoui3` now raising the exception.)  <br>  What I'm not sure about: Is it correct to raise such an exception at fp -> uint conversion?

Comment: @MattTT: Yes, as I mentioned in my answer, x86 FP->int conversion hardware instructions like `fistp` and `cvtsd2si` raise the FP invalid flag on overflow of the output.  Same for AVX-512 FP->unsigned conversions like [`vcvtsd2usi`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/VCVTSD2USI.html).  If it's unmasked it will actually take an exception, otherwise just set the flag in the x87 status register or MXCSR.  So it's definitely not wrong for an emulated conversion to do the same if the result is out of range.

Comment: I have to correct me (I was mislead by asm tag names): In both cases `__dtoui3` is called (which jumps to `_dtoui3`), but in VS2019 (16.9.16) a 32bit implementation is used, where values above 4.29...e09 lead to the exception and a return of FFFFFFFF, while in VS2017 a 64bit implementation is used, storing the result in eax & edx, so the caller can grab the 32bit (modulo) value from eax - without exception. The x64 build uses cvttsd2si in both cases. --- I learned now, that the exception is correct, since [the behavior of such conversion is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46929035).